# ng-click wont recognize changes in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to view in a `<p>` the values sent to the function `cronSave(user_id,script_id,cron_format)`. problem is `cron_format` is a `<contenteditable>` attribute and the function will only display value innitialized the table without getting the changes..
this is the table:

```
<p id="demo">Display data here</p>

<main>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
        <thead>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>script name</th>
        <th>cron format<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                <td class="userName">{{row.user_id}}</td>
                <td class="scriptName">{{row.script_id}}</td>
                <td class="cronFormat"><span contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="l in letters(row.cron_format) track by $index">{{l}}</span><button class="save"  ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)">save</button></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</main>
```

and this is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

//Table Controller
app.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope) {
$scope.data = [
      {user_id: "1", script_id: "s12", cron_format: "*/2 * * 5 *"},
      {user_id: "2", script_id: "s34", cron_format: "*/5 * * * *"},
      {user_id: "3", script_id: "s54", cron_format: "*/4 * 7 * *"},
    {user_id: "4", script_id: "s234", cron_format:  "*/6 * * * *" }
    ];
    //parse cron_format and edit each digit individually
    $scope.letters = function(row.cron_format){
        return cron_format.split(" ");
    }
    //save cron changes if exits / create if doesn't

    $scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat){
        $.post("updateCronChange.php","user_id=userId&script_id=scriptId&cron=cronFormat", function(data){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userId + scriptId + cronFormat;   // Get the element with id="demo"
        });
    }
});
```

so if in rows one user changes the cron format to `*/5 * * *` it will still display in the `"demo"`

`*/2 * * 5 *`

how can i overcome this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing Jquery with AngularJS and that is not recommended.

You are updating the innerHTML but that's not the way to do things if you're working with Angular. Instead, you need to have `ng-model` and have it updated:

```
<p id="demo">{{demoData}}</p>
```

And in your function, which also you should be using Angular's `$http` provider:

```
$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat){
        var data = //format your "user_id=userId&script_id=scriptId&cron=cronFormat" 
                   //here inside an object
        $http.post("updateCronChange.php", data).success(function(data){
            $scope.demoData = userId + scriptId + cronFormat;
        });
    }
```

**Edit**: Not sure why you have that span, but in order to change the cronFormat, it should be in an `ng-model` as well.

I changed it to be this and it works:

```
<td class="cronFormat"><input type="text" ng-model="row.cron_format"/><button class="save"  ng-click="saveCron(row.user_id,row.script_id,row.cron_format)">save</button></td>
```

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s5y3fhu/).

Comment: thanks for the help but still...it wont change the fact that the value of cron_format is not updated

Comment: @johnking Sorry missed that, take a look at the edit.